# url rewrite rule for paramters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following URL:

```
https://www.mydomain.de/termin_cancel=c502b486-e8ad-490a-a615-80307a515fc8
```

Original url:

```
https://www.mydomain.de/index.php?termin_cancel=c502b486-e8ad-490a-a615-80307a515fc8
```

rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^termin_cancel=([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?termin_cancel=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This works !

But now I have a problem with the next situation:

The url should be:

```
https://www.mydomain.de/termin_change=XXX&serviceID=XXX&firstname=XXX&lastname=XXX&email=XXX
```

original url:

```
https://www.mydomain.de/index.php?termin_change=XXX&serviceID=XXX&firstname=XXX&lastname=XXX&email=XXX
```

I don't know which htaccess rule work fo this.
It should be possible to access the parameters via php `$_GET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
RewriteRule ^termin_change=([^&]+)&serviceID=([^&]+)&firstname=([^&]+)&lastname=([^&]+)&email=([^&]+)$ /index.php?termin_change=$1&serviceID=$2&firstname=$3&lastname=$4&email=$5 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?$1 [QSA,NE,L]
```

---

OR with `/` in case your index.php is present in root directory/folder.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?$1 [QSA,NE,L]
```

OR(either put above or put following)

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/termin_change=.*/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?$1 [QSA,NE,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, something like below specifically for `termin_change=`

```
RewriteRule ^termin_change=(.+)/?$ index.php?termin_change=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: yes the direction is correct. but there are more parameters as "termin_change". For example "serviceID", "firstname", etc.